# Flutter Blue Plus Not Scanning Devices on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have created an ble application in flutter using the flutter_blue_plus library, i used both scanning and advertising features.
In android advertising and scanning both are working without any issue.
In IOS Advertising is working but scanning is not working.
Code for scanning

```
    widget.flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((List<ScanResult> results) {
      for (ScanResult result in results) {
        setState(() {
          _addDeviceTolist(
            result.device,
            result.rssi,
          );
        });
      }
    });
    widget.flutterBlue.startScan(
      withServices: [Guid('7ecbb852-c08c-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002')],
      allowDuplicates: true,
    );
```

How to make scanning work in IOS Version of the application.

Comment: Does your scan find devices when the `withServices` attribute is removed?

Comment: No I Tried that as well

Comment: Do you get any log messages stating why there are problems?

Comment: It says anther scan already in progress(IOS) but in android it works fine